# How to not wait for the python line to fully complete and jump to next line

Tags: python-3.x

For Example:

```
def abc():
    for I in range(1,10000000000):
        print(I)

def def():
    for I in range(1,1000000000000):
        print(I)

abc()
def()
```

How to let the `abc()` keep running and not to wait `abc()` to complete and jump to `def()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads to perform this:

```py
from threading import Thread

def abc():
    for I in range(1,10000000000): print(I)

def other():
    for I in range(1,10000000000): print(I)

abc_thread = Thread(target=abc)
abc_thread.start() 
# This starts the abc() function and then immediately 
# continues to the next line of code. This is possible because the 
# function is executed on another thread separate from the main program's thread
other()
```

Also as a side note, I am not sure what your implementation of this will be but because you are new, I have to point out that it is bad practice to name your functions, classes, variables, etc. to the same name as a builtin python object. This will cause headaches later on when you will run into errors.

Comment: Indeed, trying to use `def` as a function name will give a `SyntaxError`, because it is a reserved word rather than a builtin. But as you say, overriding builtins (although syntactically possible) will cause headaches.

Comment: What if the functions have inputs in them, lets say abc('asdf') and how will we run?

Comment: You would use the following: ```abc_thread = Thread(target=abc, args=('asdf'))``` then start it as per usual